# SQL query XML and return null if node is not existing

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have xml files where a node (field2) is not always present. If the node is not present i want to get null value.

```
SELECT 
    field1, field2 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         xmlField1.value('text()[1]','VARCHAR(256)') AS field1, 
         xmlField2.value('text()[1]','VARCHAR(256)') AS field2 
     FROM 
         [dbo].XMLTable t 
     CROSS APPLY 
         [XMLData].nodes('/collection/test/field1') A(xmlField1)
     CROSS APPLY 
         [XMLData].nodes('/collection/test/field2') B(xmlField2)) xmlData
```

This query works if I have both fields in the XML file, but if field2 is missing, I don't get any values returned.

Comment: I don't have experience with T-SQL, but with PLSQL and the same issue arose. What I do is that when the value is null, I simply replace it with a comment.

Comment: Side point: it might be easier and more performant to shred `.nodes('/collection/test')` then use `.value('field1/text()[1]'` as that only requires one `.nodes`

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

A minimal reproducible example is not provided.

Please try the following conceptual example.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<collection>
    <test>
        <field1>fld11</field1>
        <field2>fld12</field2>
    </test>
    <test>
        <field1>fld12</field1>
    </test>
    <test>
        <field1>fld13</field1>
        <field2/>
    </test>
</collection>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
    , c.value('(field1/text())[1]','VARCHAR(256)') AS field1
    , c.value('(field2/text())[1]','VARCHAR(256)') AS field2
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/collection/test') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID | field1 | field2 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | fld11  | fld12  |
|  1 | fld12  | NULL   |
|  1 | fld13  | NULL   |
+----+--------+--------+
```